# How to use jQuery selectors with SVGweb

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-selectors, svg, css-selectors

I want to use jQuery selectors on a SVG. On browsers with native SVG support all selectors work fine. 
But on browsers (actually, I only tested ie8), where SVGweb is using the Flash renderer, only some selectors work, eg:

```
$('#id')             /* id selectors works*/
$('#id #another-id') 
$('*')                /* universal selector works */
```

Some selectors won't work:

```
$('path')            /* type selectors don't work */
$('.region')         /* class selectors don't work */
```

Note: I didn't yet test other selectors.

My Question: How do I get them working?

NB: If this is not possible, a short explanation (and maybe some sort of work-around for this limitation) could earn the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

(using Firefox)

I'm using the embed-in-an-`<object>` approach for cross-browser compatibility:

```
<!--[if !IE]>-->
  <object data="path-to.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="object-id">
  </object>
<!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <object src="path-to.svg" classid="image/svg+xml" id="object-id">
  </object>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
  <object data="path-to.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="object-id">
  </object>
<![endif]-->
```

...then use the `<object>` node's `contentDocument` to tell `jQuery()` about this new DOM...

```
var svgdoc = $('object-id').get(0).contentDocument;
var $svg = $(svgdoc).children();
```

...and you should be able to base things off of `$svg`:

```
var $paths = $('path',$svg);
$svg.find('rect').attr('fill','blue');
```

Comment: Yes, this works for type selectors, which is nice - but it still doesn't work with class selectors like `$('.class')`, does it?

Comment: I think it should -- `$svg.find('.classname')` should give you any elements with `class="classname"`.